# ¿Por que no puedo utilizar textarea e input con DomPDF en Laravel o Cómo podría utilizarlo?

Tags: laravel, html5, dompdf

bien lo que pasa es que necesito exportar un PDF, el problema que tengo es al utilizar los `textarea` no me muestra el texto correctamente.

La siguiente imagen es el "objetivo", lo que quiero conseguir, lo que esta con amarillo son los espacios que existen entre "parrafos" (los cuales sin `textarea` no se como podría conseguirlo).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora cuando genero el PDF, la tabla que exportare, se ve así:

la primera columna esta con un `textarea`,  y todo el texto se ve de esa forma, en css le puse `text-align: justify;`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si no utilizo `text-align: justify;` se ve asi: (todo el texto en una sola linea)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CÓDIGO:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <style>
                /*######################################### T-HEAD ##########################*/

                .t-table-pdf thead tr th {
          background: #109090;
          border: rgba(25, 85, 141, 0.3) solid 1px;
          color: #FFF;
          font-size: 12px;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: middle;
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        /*######################################### T-BODY ##########################*/

        .t-table-pdf tbody tr td {
          border: #d4d4d48f solid 1px;
          color: #444444;
          font-size: 13px;
          /* vertical-align: middle; */
        }

        .t-table-pdf tbody tr .costo-referencial {
          background: transparent;
          color: #444444;
          font-size: 13px;
          text-align: right;
          margin-top: 100%;
          margin-bottom: auto;
        }

        textarea{
          background: transparent;
          border: none;
          color: #444444;
          /* font-size: 13px; */
          /* text-align: justify;           */
        }

        /*######################################### T-FOOT ##########################*/
        .t-table-pdf tfoot tr td {
          background: #109090;
          border: rgba(25, 85, 141, 0.3) solid 1px;
          font-size: 13px;
          text-align: left;
          vertical-align: middle;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          color: #FFF;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        .t-table-pdf tfoot tr td span {
          /* background: #109090; */
          /* background: red; */
          color: #FFF;
          font-size: 13px;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: middle;
          text-align: right;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
            <table class="table t-table-pdf">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre del proyeto referencia</th>
                        <th>Tipo</th>
                        <th>Beneficios</th>
                        <th>Descripción de elementos involucrados</th>
                        <th>Costo Referencial</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($referencia as $item)
                    <tr>
                        <td class=""><textarea>{{$item->dato}}</textarea></td>
                        <td class="">{{$item->dato}}</td>
                        <td class="">{{$item->dato}}</td>
                        <td class="">{{$item->dato}}</td>
                        <td class="costo-referencial">$ {{$item->dato}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                        <td>Promedio de Módulos </td>
                        <td class="text-right">$ {{$costo->dato}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/textarea) es para ingresar texto en un formulario, vos acá no necesitás eso. Usa una etiqueta [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/p). Para que te respete los espacios (no se como es el texto original), probá hacer: `{!! nl2br(e($item->dato)) !!}`.

Comment: O usa la etiqueta <pre> en vez de <texarea>. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/pre

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas ambas sirven, conocía lo de los `<textarea>` para formularios, por eso preguntaba por que o cómo utilizarlos con DomPDF.

Comment: @azeós, si pones como respuesta y no como un comentario, para hacer que la pregunta ya aparezca como solucionada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La etiqueta [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/textarea) se usa en formularios. Lo adecuado sería que utilices [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/p) o, como sugirió @porloscerrosΨ, [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/pre), pero no estoy seguro de que sea lo más adecuado.

Ahora, si el texto original tiene saltos de línea, eso tenés que representarlo con la etiqueta [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/br). PHP tiene una función que se llama [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) que convierte automáticamente todos los saltos de línea en `<br>`, el problema es que al usar `{{ }}` de Blade, estás *escapando* todas las etiquetas HTML y el `<br>` se vería como texto.

Para poder combinar todo, lo que tenés que hacer es:

```php
{!! nl2br(e($item->dato)) !!}}
```

La sintaxis `{!! !!}` es para mostrar la información [sin escapar](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data). Dentro llamamos a `nl2br()` para que cree los `<br>` y por último a [`e()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-e) que es un helper de Laravel para escapar los caracteres HTML. Es decir, escapamos todos los caracteres menos el `<br>` que generamos nosotros.

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió.